# Performance Issue when adding one or more columns to existing dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm working on python 2.7, pandas ( version 0.18.1 ) data frames. I have to add multiple columns to a data frame. For that I tried to solve in below way

`data` is my data frame (column size : morethan 50) having size approximately 800MB

my sample data is like below

```
+---+---+----+----+---+---------+---+----+----+---+----------+
| a | b | c  | d  | e |    f    | g | h  | i  | j | discount |
+---+---+----+----+---+---------+---+----+----+---+----------+
| 0 | 1 | 100|    |   | 65497.6 |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 | 1 |    |    |   | 73882.8 |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 1 | 0 |    |    |   | 88588   |   | 22 |    |   |        0 |
| 0 | 1 |    |    |   | 106480  |   | 20 | 10 |   |        0 |
| 1 |   |    |    |   | 52500   |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 |   | 20 | 10 |   | 22997.5 |   |    |    |   |        0 |
|   |   |    |    |   |         |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 | 1 |    | 20 |   | 0       |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 | 0 |    |    |   | 10520   |   |    |    |   |        0 |
+---+---+----+----+---+---------+---+----+----+---+----------+
```

Method1 :

```
for metricColumn in metricColumns:
    if metricColumn not in dataColumns:
        data[metricColumn] = 0
```

Method2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for metricColumn in metricColumns:
    if metricColumn not in dataColumns:
        df[metricColumn] = 0
data[df.columns] = df
data[df.columns] = 0
```

Method3 :

```
appendColumns = []
for metricColumn in metricColumns:
    if metricColumn not in dataColumns:
        appendColumns.append(metricColumns)
data = pd.concat([data,pd.DataFrame(columns=appendColumns)])
```

All these 3 ways it is taking lot of time and memory i.e. approximately 10 minutes and 50GB of memory

Please help me how can I improve or please let me know if i'm doing any mistakes

Comment: Can you post some representative data?  I just mocked up a 800MB frame, and adding 45 columns using "method 1" took ~45 ms.

Comment: What are the rules for those columns? Which values are allowed? If they are binary, or very small numbers, you can use a different dtype which would save memory. I'm not sure how many zeroes you have to hit 50GB of memory usage though.

Comment: @ayhan I just wanted to add to columns existing data frame with values 0, I'm not sure about the exact count of new columns size